# Get dynamic mySQL table column with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-columns

Normally all the basic PHP-MYSQL-SELECT tutorials are based on this code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_num_rows($results);
if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // You have $row['ID'], $row['Category'], $row['Summary'], $row['Text']
    }
}
```

but for this I need to know the column name like 'ID', 'Category', 'Summary' or 'Text'.
And if I add in phpmyadmin a new column like 'Email', I also have to add `$row['Email']` to the php script.

How can I make this step dynamic?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: [PHP-MYSQL TUTORIAL](https://www.udemy.com/php-mysql-tutorial/) its a good form to understand all this...

Answer (score 0):

regarding this particular question, for what do you need rows? if you just want to print them do print_r($row) and they'll be there, if you want to do something with them make foreach loop like this

```
foreach($row as $k=>$cell)
{
    //do something with cell
}
```

but as lot of other people would tell you, use PDO.

Comment: I'm sure that if you google for PDO tutorials you would find many. It's not that complicated at all, just when you start learning, don't be afraid to use prepared statements, as they are what makes PDO awesome. Start simple project and look at php.net documentation, it's all you need. Goodluck.

Comment: so PDO would be better than MySQLi?

Comment: My opinion is yes. Read comment from zfus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_fetch_array()` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and you will be able to use indexes instead of names, however, in any case, order is not guaranteed unless you define it yourself in your query, but depending of what you want to do with the results, it can help.

Standard nag: Use MySQLi.

Comment: Rafael says use "MySQLi" / Dexa says "PDO" - what should i really use now?

Comment: I'd recommend PDO. If you desire to move to a different database in the future, PDO might reduce a lot of work. An article about [PDO vs. MySQLi](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/) might help.

Comment: MySQLi is closer to the old MySQL functions, while PDO, is very different, if you're starting on PHP/MySQL development choose PDO, if you're migrating and old application use MySQLi.